# Verify copied file using Perl and SCP

Tags: perl, scp, verify

How do I verify a copied file on a remote server using Perl [SCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) or is it possible? Below is the Perl command that I am using. I cannot use [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) so my options are somewhat limited.

```
$scpe->scp("/u02/oraclebackup/$tar_file","HOST:/u04/orabkup/oraclebackup/oemp/");
```

Comment: copy the remote back to local and `cmp` locally probably isn't reliable... What you can use on the remote side? And, btw, it is possible to get a "wrong" copy over the `scp`?

Comment: I agree with @jm666; unless something happened on the network, your almost always guaranteed it transferred successfully.

Comment: Perhaps I am being a little too cautious. This is going to run as a script in cron so I won't be able to monitor it directly and who knows what kind of network issues could arise in the future. This is copying our database backups so I wanted to make sure that it was ok before deleting the local copy.

Comment: I thought `scp` had built-in verification.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using `Net::SCP::Expect`. Read this section of the [`perldoc`](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::SCP::Expect#error_handler-sub-ref): "error_handler(sub ref) ..."

Comment: Yes, I am @chrsblck. Can you give me an example of how it used because I can't seem to find anything useful? Thanks.

Comment: As SCP runs on top of SSH it is shielded against network errors. When scp says the file has been transferred correctly it really means it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've found a solution to my problem and while it doesn't directly verify the copy it will stop the script if there is an error beside the one that is expected. Here is my  code:

```
$scpe->error_handler( \&scp_errors );
$scpe->scp( "/u02/oraclebackup/$tar_file",
    "HOST:/u04/orabkup/oraclebackup/oemp/" );

#Error trapping with exception for known harmless error
sub scp_errors {
    my $line = shift;

    if ( $line =~ /scp timed out while trying to connect to/ ) { 
        return (0);
    } else {
        return (1);
    }   
}
```

This seems to have solved both of my problems. Thanks @chrsblck

Comment: NP. Also, note that a "simple 'croak()' call will occur" if you don't set up a `error_handler`. If you're unfamiliar with [`Carp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html#NAME), I suggest you change that ;)